# $.getJSON doesn't work with httpd

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

$.getJSON doesn't work with httpd. 
But the code are worked well with IIS7.

How can run $.getJSON with httpd?

```
 $.getJSON("/ihis/casesRecieve/loadHospitalList.php", function(json){
        $("#hospital").autocomplete({
            source: json,

            change: function(){
                var engineer = $.post("/ihis/casesRecieve/loadEngineer.php",{hospital: $("#hospital").val()});
                engineer.done(function(data){
                    $("#engineer").val(data);
                });
                $("#division").load("/ihis/casesRecieve/loadDivision.php",{
                    hospital: $("#hospital").val()
                },function(){
                    $("#division option:eq(0)").attr("selected","selected");
                    $("#contact").load("/ihis/casesRecieve/loadContact.php",{
                        division: $("#division option:selected").val(),
                        hospital: $("#hospital").val()
                    });
                    $("#instrument").load("/ihis/casesRecieve/loadInstrument.php",{
                        division: $("#division").val(),
                        hospital: $("#hospital").val()
                    });
                    $("#division").show();
                    $("#contact").show();
                    $("#instrument").show();
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Please help~

Comment: Wait. *doesn't work* is not a valid issue description, and web server won't affect client-side JavaScript operation as well. Check Developer Console in your browser for error message.

Comment: You might try emitting the `Content-Type: application/javascript` header in your response to see if that helps.